# Pass a file to AWS Lambda via API Gateway

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to pass a .csv file (less than 5MB) to a Lambda to perform some processing and I am not sure what would be the best way of doing this. Currently, I pass it as JSON string property and it works but I'm not sure if there are any pitfalls to this approach.

Current API:

```
{
"fileMetadata1" : "some meta data like a name for the request",
"date": "date file was last modified for example",
       ...
"fileData", "the actual data of file in String format"
}
```

Ideally id like "fileData" to be of type `InputStream` in my input object model, but that didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

A very common pattern is to put your file to s3, and then make your lambda read it from s3. You can either start the lambda from a s3 event, or by passing it the address of the file to your invocation.

This is generally a better idea, as you won't have to care about input size limitations anymore.

Comment: I have considered that approach and there are reasons why my use case can't use it. Other than that, is there a better way to pass the file into lambda via API Gateway?